# Can I view uploaded photos on iOS?

Tags: iphone, ios, photos

iOS offers some automatic albums out-of-the-box (e.g. selfies, panoramas, etc.). However, I see no "uploaded" album. I have always found this inconvenient, and today I found out that Android has albums with the photos uploaded to each service (Messenger, WhatsApp, etc). Is it possible in any way for me to see (and ideally also delete) all photos ever uploaded anywhere?

Comment: What defines an uploaded photo? I’m not clear on this terminology as it applies to iCloud or Photos app.

Answer (score 1):

No, the Photos app does not offer a computed "Uploaded" folder that automatically gathers all photos ever uploaded across services.

There's also no other place in the system, nor any log file in the system, that automatically gathers a list of photos uploaded to services via apps on the device.